# Get my video in browser

Tags: javascript, html, twilio

I use Twilio API to create video chat between iPad and laptop.

It works good for iPad: I have 2 screens (big screen contains video from laptop, small screen contains video from iPad).
But I have only one big screen in browser at laptop (with video from iPad), and I haven't small screen with video from camera at laptop.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/v1/twilio-video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var accessToken = "..."
        const Video = Twilio.Video;
        const client = new Video.Client(accessToken);
        const localMedia = new Video.LocalMedia();

        Video.getUserMedia().then(mediaStream => {
            localMedia.addStream(mediaStream);
        });

        client.connect({
            to: 'my-room',
            localMedia: localMedia
        }).then(room => {
            const localParticipant = room.localParticipant;                       
            room.participants.forEach(participant => {                    
                participant.on('trackAdded', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Added an AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Added a VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });
                participant.on('trackRemoved', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Removed an AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Removed a VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });    
                participant.on('trackEnabled', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Enabled AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Enabled VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });    
                participant.on('trackDisabled', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Disabled AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Disabled VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });

                const element = participant.media.attach();
                document.body.appendChild(element);

                participant.media.tracks.forEach(track => {
                    track.attach('#track-view');
                });
            });

            room.once('participantConnected', participant => {
                console.log('Participant "%s" has connected to the Room', participant.identity);
            });

            room.once('participantDisconnected', participant => {                
                console.log('Participant "%s" has disconnected from Room', participant.identity);
            });

        }, error => {
            console.error('Failed to connect to the Room', error);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the best way to show small screen with video from laptop in my laptop's browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me as though you aren't attaching the local media to the page anywhere. Could you try something like:

```
Video.getUserMedia().then(mediaStream => {
    localMedia.addStream(mediaStream);
    const element = localMedia.attach();
    document.body.appendChild(element);
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hello @philnash - do you have a few minutes to help me with a similar issue?  It is linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661361/twilio-programmable-video-js-ionic  (I am pretty stuck at the moment :( )